# Why playing 180 degrees out-of-phase oscillators in Sylenth1 doesn't result in silence?

Tags: synthesizer

I've been playing around with [Lennar Digital - Sylenth1](https://www.lennardigital.com/downloads/), experimenting using just two sine wave oscillators. If I put them 180 degrees out-of-phase, I still hear a tone being played when I hit a key.

Are they not simply superimposing the two out-of-phase sine waves, which should result in no wave?

Comment: Are the oscillators detuned?

Comment: No I double checked that they have the exact same settings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose this type of thing without hands on, but here are a few things to try:

- the phase control only works if RETRIG is active (in both OSCs, for what you want)
- same number of voices in both OSCs?
- INV should not be active in either OSCs (or active in one of the them but with PHASE realigned to 0 in both of them)
- are you sure you don't have a sound active in the other part (A or B) that you are not working on at the moment?

If none of that works perhaps you can post a screen shot of the settings you're using.

Comment: Ah, activating RETRIG did it. I'm guess it plays the wave from the start again on keypress? That would make sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, that's the meaning of retrig.